# AWS VPC Setup for RDS access

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am setting up a RDS Maria database on AWS however am unable to get the security settings correct to access it from a non-AWS PC. It is on a VPC in us-west-2b with the following settings:

`Subnet Group: Default
Subnets: us-west-2a; us-west-2b; us-west-2c
Security Group: rds-launch-wizard
Publically Accessible: Yes
Encryption Enabled: No`

All the subnets have the same Network ALC Settings:

`Inbound Rules: <my ip>/32:3306 ALLOW; 0.0.0.0/0:ALL DENY
Outbound Rules: 0.0.0.0/0:3306 ALLOW; 0.0.0.0/0:ALL DENY`

The Security group has the same inbound and outbound rules:

`Inbound Rules: <my ip>/32:3306 ALLOW; 0.0.0.0/0:ALL DENY
Outbound Rules: 0.0.0.0/0:3306 ALLOW; 0.0.0.0/0:ALL DENY`

There is a (default setup) Internet Gateway applied to the VPC.  I have not added any subnet associations to the route table.

The database is online.  Are there any additional settings which I should be looking at.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not limit the port in Subnet Network ACL Outbound Rules, just leave `0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW` (that is because the clients will use the random port to connect to mysql). Also, `Subnet Network ACL` is usually not used for limiting access to resources, only security groups.
In Security group, again do not modify Outbound rules, leave `All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0`.

Finally, there are no `DENY` rules in Security Group settings, please double check which screen are you getting the above rules from?

Comment: You are correct; about the DENY rules in the Security Group Settings - I checked them on AWS then copied from the line above in error.

I have now set the outbound to ALL ports in the Subnet and Security groups and it is working.  Thanks!